# C#/.net Reuse code chunks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In my project, there are a lot of code chunks that a reused under different conditions. These chunks are just a few lines of code. The calls of these chunks are spread all over the program and some of theme depend ob which mode the program is running.

I now want to provide this code in a easy to access way with a good performance.
I've two attempts in mind.

a) Create a static class with functions, each containing one chunk of code.

b) Creating several small classes (components) each with an execute method holding one chunk of code.

I'm not sure which is a clean way to handle that situation or if there is any best practice approach.

If you need more information, just let me know.

EDIT: I try to give a short example. The program can run in two different modes. Each mode has the same workflows but they differ slightly in the two modes. One workflow is about loading another assembly and setup communication between both programs. In both modes I have to call functions that are not needed in the other mode. Also this calls appear in other parts of the program.
These chunks are always about calling some functions at the right time in the correct order.

```
void WorkflowXY()
{
    Foo.Do();
    Foo.DoMore();
    if(Mode.A)
    {
        //Chunk1, several lines of code, mostly calling other functions
    }
    else
    {
        //Chunk2, several lines of code, mostly calling other functions
    }
}

void SomewhereElse()
{
    //Code
    //Chunk2
    //more code
}

void InACompletlyDifferentNamespace()
{
    //Code
    //Chunk1
    //more code
}
```

Comment: Any examples of these "chunks of code"?

Comment: It is pretty common to have a static `Helpers` class or something to that effect. If you have a collection of helpers which are mainly geared to a specific purpose, you might have a `PurposeHelpers` class, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `Helper` classes, if you can. They're clear SRP violations and tend to become dumping grounds for loosely related methods.

I favour your second option. IMHO, classes cannot be too small. One class, one job.

[This](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) is worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Your "chunks of code" is a little bit unclear. Anyway, consider [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604137/helper-methods-in-c-static-or-non-static) concerning static vs non static. It mentions also an `extension` method. If you do not wanna apply extensions, then [another issue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/helper-static-methods-in-tdd) could fit for your purpose.